# Passing DOM element ID to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I have the following codes in my Django template, in this exact order and proximity:

```
<div id="test-modal">
  <p id="test-text">Display on click</p>
</div>

<button id="test_button">Test Click</button>
<p id="test">Replace This Text</p>

<script src="{% static 'js/checkin.js' %}"></script>
```

In my css file:

```
#test-modal {
    display: none;
}
```

I have a `div` called `test-modal` which is initially invisible. I want it to be visible when the button `test-button` is clicked. Also, for debugging, I include a `test` text, which is to be replaced with `Hello World` when the same button is clicked.
Here is my JavaScrip code:
`checkin.js`

```
function showModal(modalName) {
    let modal = document.getElementById(modalName)
    modalName.style.display = "block";

}

var test_id = document.getElementById("test")
var test_button = document.getElementById("test_button")

test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        test_id.innerText = "Hello World";
        showModal("test-modal");
})
```

When I click the button, only the `Hello World` text is displayed. The `test-modal` is still invisible. I am guessing there is something I am doing wrong about passing the ID into the function? If anyone could advise, thanks very much.

Comment: rather than `modalName.style.displsy` use `modal.style.display`

Comment: Glad to help. :-)